# Gain or Loss or Nothing??

Tags: algebra-precalculus

I had 2 bicycles. I've sold both of them for 500 rupees each.On 1 I get 20% profit and on the other 20%  loss. Then what is the total gain or loss or nothing??

Comment: I think you'll get 0% profit. What do you think?

Comment: One bicycle costs $625$ and the other $416.67$. However, you must show your own thoughts on how you solved this problem. Homework problems are yours not ours, when you are not willing to put in your own effort.

Answer (score 3):

Let the cost price of the cycles be $x$ and $y$ rupees. Let the cycle costing $x$ rupees be sold for a $20\%$ profit.
Then,
$$\frac{500-x}{x}=\frac{20}{100}$$
$$2500-5x=x$$
$$x=\frac{2500}{6}=416.\bar6$$
Similarly,
$$\frac{y-500}{y}=\frac{20}{100}$$
$$5y-2500=y$$
$$4y=2500$$
$$y=625$$
$$\text{Total cost}=625+416.67=1041.67$$
$$\text{Amount received}=500+500=1000$$
$$\text{Loss}=41.67\text{ rupees}$$